# VBA to filter transaction dates that are after the date entered on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to filter the transactions with a date that's after a date entered in Cell "P1". I wrote below codes but it doesn't filter anything at all.
Can someone please help? Many thanks

```
Sub DateFilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("OpenPO")

tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheet1.Range("P1")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the filter criteria **after a date entered in Cell "P1"**? If yes, after it in which direction? If down, please use Sheet1.Range("P2"). If to the right, Sheet1.Range("Q1")... If the filtered data should be after "P1", can you tell us what address `tbl` has? And do you want filtering on the second column of the table?

Comment: Try this `Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Sheet1.Range("P1"), "mm/dd/yyyy")` .. Reference [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/autofilter-vba-less-than-or-equal-to-date.653780/) ... worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because dates are numbers you can use `.Value2` property, that doesn't use Date type and returns Double instead Date. Side note: to do this you is not nessesary a helper variables.

```vb
Sub DateFilter()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("OpenPO").Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheet1.Range("P1").Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: It's working nicely as I need it to be. Thank you very much.